# How to get the index of object/array by comparing its checked value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object 'obj', whose values are populating into html as checkbox value. Now when I uncheck any checkbox, I need to get the index of array of object of which its belong to by comparing with the array of object 'obj'.For Ex- suppose I uncheck first 'createddate' , then I should get index as 0 so on..  Here is the code below

### html

```
<div class="menu-outer-block">
    <div class="menu-block" id="menu-block">
      <div id="menu"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

### script

```
let Obj = /* this.guidelineObj;*/ [{
        mainitem: "My item 1",
        Seconditem: {
          createddate: "30-01-02",
          enddate: "30-01-03"
        }
      },
      {
        mainitem: "My item 2",
        Seconditem: {
          createddate: "30-01-02",
          enddate: "30-01-03"
        }
      }
    ];
    const lines1 = [];
    const columns = {};
    Obj.reverse().forEach(col => {
      lines1.push('<div>' + col.mainitem + '</div>');
      Object.keys(col.Seconditem).forEach(key => {
        columns[key] = true;
        const checked = columns[key] ? 'checked' : '';
        lines1.push(
          "<label><input  class='menu-checkbox' type='checkbox' name='" +
          key +
          `' ` +
          checked +
          '>' +
          key +
          '</label>'
        );
      });
    });
    document.getElementById("menu").innerHTML = lines1.join('<br>');
    const dropDown = document.querySelector('#menu');
    dropDown.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');
    dropDown.addEventListener('change', e => {
      console.log(e)
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already creating the checkboxes dynamically you can simply add a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) holding the `mainitem` value of the object. It is then trivial to retrieve this from the `event.target` (`event.target.dataset.mainitem`) and use it to either [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the object in the array or [`findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) of the object in the array by comparing `mainitem` values.

```
  const mainitem = e.target.dataset.mainitem;
  // find the object
  const o = Obj.find(o => o.mainitem === mainitem);
  // or find the index
  const oIndex = Obj.findIndex(o => o.mainitem === mainitem);
```

**Note** you are calling [`reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) on your array before your loop, which mutates your array *in place*, so the results of `findIndex()` will be reversed from the original order.

```js
let Obj = [{ mainitem: "My item 2", id: 1, Seconditem: { createddate: "30-01-02", enddate: "30-01-03" } }, { mainitem: "My item 2", id: 2, Seconditem: { createddate: "30-01-02", enddate: "30-01-03" } }, { mainitem: "My item 2", id: 3, Seconditem: { createddate: "30-01-02", enddate: "30-01-03" } }];
const lines1 = [];

const columns = {};
Obj.reverse().forEach(col => {
  lines1.push('<div>' + col.mainitem+ ' id: '+ col.id + '</div>');
  Object.keys(col.Seconditem).forEach(key => {
    columns[key] = true;
    const checked = columns[key] ? 'checked' : '';
    lines1.push(
      `<label>
      <input class='menu-checkbox' type='checkbox' name='${key}' data-id='${col.id}' ${checked} >
      ${key}
      </label>`
    );
  });
});

document.getElementById("menu").innerHTML = lines1.join('<br>');
const dropDown = document.querySelector('#menu');
dropDown.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');
dropDown.addEventListener('change', e => {
  const id = e.target.dataset.id;
  // find the object
  const o = Obj.find(o => o.id == id);
  // or find the index
  const oIndex = Obj.findIndex(o => o.id == id);
  console.log(oIndex, ' - ', o);
})
```

```html
<div class="menu-outer-block">
    <div class="menu-block" id="menu-block">
      <div id="menu"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. If I change the obj array to [{
  mainitem: "My item 2",
  id : 1,
  Seconditem: {
    createddate: "30-01-02",
    enddate: "30-01-03"
  }
},
{
  mainitem: "My item 2",
  id : 2,
  Seconditem: {
    createddate: "30-01-02",
    enddate: "30-01-03"
  }
},
{
  mainitem: "My item 2",
  id : 3,
  Seconditem: {
    createddate: "30-01-02",
    enddate: "30-01-03"
  }
}
];     its not showing correct index

Comment: `find()` and `findIndex()` return the first element that matches, so you will need to search by a unique property, say `id` and alter the data attribute and search comparison accordingly.

Comment: I tried replacing  mainitem with id, its not working

Comment: `id` is a number in the object and a string when you retrieve it from the HTML. Replace the `===` with `==`

Comment: edited with your new data Obj showing the differences.